# I need to convert a mysql Query to CakePHP conditions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-1.3

I am having trouble understanding how to turn this into a native cakephp query using the find function. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT * FROM `seo_web_directories` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `seo_site_statuses` 
  WHERE site_id = $queryData) as t1 
ON `seo_web_directories`.id = t1.web_directory_id
```

The variable is a dynamic value that is set when the function is called

Comment: I am currently using the query function to pass in the query above however i need to use the paginate helper. so if you could explain how to use this sort of query with paginate i would greatly appreciate that but every article and method i have tried doesn't seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a suboptimal ORM , you should find a way to using this query directly with models. Try looking at [Model::query()](http://api13.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelquery) method [[source]](http://api13.cakephp.org/view_source/model/#line-2452).

ORMs ( especially ones implementing [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) ) should not be used for joins. They end up doing loops for each new table you add to the `JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->WebDirectory->find('all', array('conditions' => array('verified' => 0),'joins' => array(
  array(
    'table' => 'seo_site_statuses',
    'type' => 'left',
    'alias' => 't1',
    'conditions' => array('WebDirectory.id' => ' t1.web_directory_id', 't1.site_id =' . $id)))));
```

alright here is the converted query i was able to figure out... maybe one more example will help someone else figure out how to do this...

However I ended up using a direct query because the above find was requiring too much memory and time for the recursion as mentioned by the above answer.

```
function paginate($id, $recursive = null, $extra = array(), $limit = 50, $page = 1){
  $page = ($page * $limit) - $limit;

  if(!empty($extra)){
    $OrderBy = "ORDER BY ";
    foreach ($extra as $key => $value) {

      $OrderBy .= $key . " " . $value;
    }
  }else{
    $OrderBy = "ORDER BY t2.page_rank DESC";
  }

  return $this->query('SELECT * FROM `seo_web_directories` as t2 
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `seo_site_statuses` WHERE site_id = ' . $id['Site.id'] . ') as t1
  ON `t2`.id = t1.web_directory_id WHERE t2.`verified` = 0 ' . $OrderBy . ' LIMIT ' . $page . ', ' . $limit);

 // return $this->WebDirectory->find('all', compact('conditions', 'joins', 'limit', 'page', 'recursive'));
}

function paginateCount($conditions = null, $recursive = 0, $extra = array())
{
return $this->WebDirectory->find('count', array('conditions' => array('verified' => 0)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help also. Enter your Mysql and convert. This will automatically convert query to cakephp format and you can understand that easily.

http://dogmatic69.com/sql-to-cakephp-find-converter